# Can the ASUS Vivobook 15X (M1503IA-L1019, with Ryzen 7) laptop support a 2TB SSD?

Tags: ssd, asus-laptop

I want to buy this laptop: [ASUS 15.6" Vivobook 15X OLED M1503IA, AMD Ryzen 7 4800H.](https://www.asus.com/ro/Laptops/For-Home/Vivobook/Vivobook-15X-OLED-M1503-AMD-Ryzen-4000-series/techspec/)

But I need 2TB storage space. Does anyone know if this laptop supports a 2TB SSD ?

On the Asus website, it does not specify anything about the maximum supported capacity, it only says that it is available in 512GB and 1TB variants. I assume that this is not the maximum supported capacity, but the capacity with which it is delivered when you buy it.

Comment: A new PC that would not support a 2TB drive would deserve being trashed :)

Comment: @PierU, I totally agree! Especially since this laptop has no HDD support at all. I think that the minimum necessary storage space today on a computer is 2TB. Now, in my old laptop, in addition to the SSD on the M2, I also have a 1TB HDD, plus another 1TB HDD inserted instead of the optical drive. And I feel that I cannot function with less than that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the *1x M.2 2280 PCIe 3.0x4* should support 2TB NVMe drives.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a Samsung 970 EVO Pro 2TB SSD and I can confirm that is suported by ASUS Vivobook 15X !